# Tkinter: Prevent Canvas component from shrinking when adding components via grid()

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So, I have a canvas component (size=700x700) to which I want to add four other components (size of each = 100x100). The size is defined on the constructors of both the parent and child components. What I want to do is add the four child components in a grid() way, so that they are all centered on the center of the parent component.

However, what happens is that the parent component seems to shrink, adjusting its size so that the four child components can barely fit.

I am using the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700,bg="black")
sticky=["se","sw","ne","nw"]

for i in range(4):
    c = tk.Canvas(canvas, height=100, width=100, bg="red")
    c.grid(row=i//2, column=i%2,sticky=sticky[i])

canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I cannot post pictures, so I hope I have described the problem well enough.

Comment: You shouldn't be adding items to the canvas with `grid`. That's not how the canvas is designed to be used. The items won't be scrollable.

Comment: Οk, so what would be a better approach to do what i want to do?

Comment: That's hard to say, it's not clear what you want to do. It depends on what you are using the canvas for, and whether or not you expect to be able to scroll items on the canvas.

Comment: I don't want to be able to scroll items on the canvas. I am trying to implement a digital version of a board game (Azul, if you've heard of it). The parent canvas represents an area from which players can pick up tokens (represented by the child components). This area gets refilled with 4 tokens every new round, so I thought that a good way to display the child components would be on a grid way on the parent area. If my goal is still not clear, check the image on the next comment, I want to implement a disc with the 4 tiles on it.

Comment: https://m.media-amazon.com/images/S/aplus-media-library-service-media/8179c960-c16a-4d9a-a301-ca120c912ea9.__CR0,0,500,500_PT0_SX300_V1___.png

Comment: If this is the case, why don't you want the canvas to shrink to fit the grid of widgets?

Comment: Because then the disc canvas gets too small, and is almost entirely covered by the child components. Let's say I want to have the disc component with a radius of 20 and the square tile components with a size of 5x5. If I Place 4 of them on the disc, I want the remaining disc area to be visible, which doesn't happen when I use the grid() function. I have somehow managed to make it better using the padx, pady attributes, however the result is still not optimal...